# Cant find keypair module

Tags: solana-program, nft, wallet, address

I want to check if a wallet contain an NFT by its address, but when I try to import keypair module I get an error that it does not exist.

> Cannot find reference 'keypair' in '**init**.py'

```
import os
import json
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from nft_addresses import nft_addresses

# Set up Solana RPC endpoint
rpc_endpoint = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'
client = Client(rpc_endpoint)

# Set up Solana wallet keypair
wallet_keypair = Keypair.from_secret_key(bytes.fromhex(os.environ.get('WALLET_SECRET_KEY')))

# Define Discord bot command
async def check_nft(ctx):
    # Get user's Solana wallet address
    user_address = 'user-address-here'

    # Check if user holds one of the NFTs
    for nft_address in nft_addresses:
        token_account_info = await client.get_account_info(nft_address)
        token_data = json.loads(token_account_info['data'][0])
        for account in token_data['accountList']:
            if account['account'] == user_address and account['amount'] > 0:
                await ctx.send('You hold one of the NFTs in our collection!')
                return

    await ctx.send('Sorry, you do not hold any NFTs in our collection.')

# Add Discord bot command to client
client.add_command('check_nft', check_nft)

# Connect bot to Discord server
client.run(os.environ.get('DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN'))
```

Is the keypair module deprecated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use `from solders.keypair import Keypair`. This was deprecated in the latest solana-py update. This happened with a lot of features. https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

For those who come later, the answer has changed since @pixeled replied.  The module has been refactored to use a new module called [solders](https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders), written in Rust.

The new import is:

```
from solders.keypair import Keypair
```